# Changing the terminal color permanently in raspberry pi

Tags: bash, terminal, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi4

I tried to change the color of my terminal `pi@ajeeth:~ $`  in raspberry pi to red I mean the letters to red and the background of the terminal to blue(not the whole background only terminal's)using `setterm -foreground green -background red`  but then it did not change the color of the letter and changed only the background for a single command but I want it forever so, could you tell me a code which changes the letter of a terminal permanently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put something like this in your ~/.bashrc or ~/.bash_profile to at least alter your PS1

```
export PS1="\e[40;31m\$USER@\$HOSTNAME:\$(echo \$PWD | sed 's@$HOME@~@') \$\e[m "
```